# When would Cassandra not provide C, A, and P with W/R set to QUORUM?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

When both read and write are set to quorum, I can be guaranteed the client will always get the latest value when reading.

I realize this may be a novice question, but I'm not understanding how this setup doesn't provide consistency, availability, and partitioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a quorum, you are unavailable (i.e. won't accept reads or writes) if there aren't enough replicas available. You can choose to relax and read / write on lower consistency levels granting you availability, but then you won't be consistent.

There's also the case where a quorum on reads and writes guarantees you the latest "written" data is retrieved. However, if a coordinator doesn't know about required partitions being down (i.e. gossip hasn't propagated after 2 of 3 nodes fail), it will issue a write to 3 replicas [assuming quorum consistency on a replication factor of 3.] The one live node will write, and the other 2 won't (they're down). The write times out (it doesn't fail). A write timeout where even one node has writte IS NOT a write failure. It's a write "in progress". Let's say the down nodes come up now. If a client next requests that data with quorum consistency, one of two things happen:

1. Request goes to one of the two downed nodes, and to the "was live" node. Client gets latest data, read repair triggers, all is good.
2. Request goes to the two nodes that were down. OLD data is returned (assuming repair hasn't happened). Coordinator gets digest from third, read repair kicks in. This is when the original write is considered "complete" and subsequent reads will get the fresh data. All is good, but one client will have received the old data as the write was "in progress" but not "complete". There is a very small rare scenario where this would happen. One thing to note is that write to cassandra are upserts on keys. So usually retries are ok to get around this problem, however in case nodes genuinely go down, the initial read may be a problem.

Typically you balance your consistency and availability requirements. That's where the term tunable consistency comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Said that on the web it's full of links that disprove (or at least try to) the Brewer's CAP theorem ... from the theorem's point of view the C say that

> all nodes see the same data at the same time

Which is quite different from the guarantee that a client will always retrieve fresh information. Strictly following the theorem, in your situation, the C it's not respected.

Comment: Actually "all nodes see the same data at the same time" is not entirely true.  In Brewer's original paper "Harvest, Yield, and Scalable Tolerant Systems," he defined Consistency as "single-copy ACID consistency."  Essentially, the cluster only needs to contain a single up-to-date copy of the data.  This definition is also reflected in his 2012 article "CAP Twelve Years Later: How the rules have changed": http://www.infoq.com/articles/cap-twelve-years-later-how-the-rules-have-changed

Answer (score 0):

The DataStax documentation contains a section on [Configuring Data Consistency](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html).  In looking through all of the available consistency configurations, For QUORUM it states:

> Returns the record with the most recent timestamp after a quorum of replicas has responded regardless of data center.  Ensures strong consistency if you can tolerate some level of failure.

Note that last part "tolerate some level of failure."  Right there it's indicating that **by using QUORUM consistency you are sacrificing availability** (A).

The document referenced above also further defines the QUORUM level, stating that your replication factor comes into play as well:

> If consistency is top priority, you can ensure that a read always
>   reflects the most recent write by using the following formula:
>
> (nodes_written + nodes_read) > replication_factor
>
> For example, if your application is using the QUORUM consistency level
>   for both write and read operations and you are using a replication
>   factor of 3, then this ensures that 2 nodes are always written and 2
>   nodes are always read. The combination of nodes written and read (4)
>   being greater than the replication factor (3) ensures strong read
>   consistency.

In the end, it all depends on your application requirements.  If your application needs to be highly-available, ONE is probably your best choice.  On the other hand, if you need strong-consistency, then QUORUM (or even ALL) would be the better option.